# How do I get porcelain out of cylinders

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, cadillac, cts

I was changing my spark plugs on my Cadillac CTs and the porcelain on the spark plug broke into pieces and a piece half the size of a Churrio fell inside my cylinder and when I look inside the cylinder I don’t see it down there how do I get it out I’ve been told to crank the engine and hope it flys out but I’m trying to use that as my last resort because I don’t want to damage my engine.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Cheap (much cheaper than a new engine) borescopes are available on, e.g., Amazon - a flexible fiber optic probe attached to a hand-held screen to see into dark corners. Use one to find the chunk (which might just be the largest piece). Then use a flexible grabber and, guided by the fiber optic, well, grab the chunk.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by attaching a short length of garden hose to a vacuum cleaner and inserting the pipe into the spark plug hole to suck the bits out.  If you cant come up with something better, you should be able to temporarily join the hose pipe to the vacuum using some duct tape, .  Moving the hose pipe around should get you around the piston top.  If you use a fresh vacuum cleaner bag, you will be able to see if you have collected any bits in the clean bag.

Answer (score 0):

Do not crank the engine with a solid object in a cylinder.
Your last resort should be to open the engine, not risk damaging it.
As mentioned in other anwsers, buy a cheap borescope and try the vacuum technique.